# How to use Void in C++ without getting an Error about Argument

Tags: c++, tuples, void, root-framework

I am trying to create a simple tree using C++ to run in ROOT using this tutorial here: https://www.niser.ac.in/sercehep2017/notes/RootTutorial_TTree.pdf.

However, Why do I get this error:

```
Processing examples/tree_example1.C("../trisignal/Events/run_01/tag_1_delphes_events.root")...
input_line_9:2:2: error: no matching function for call to 'tree_example1'
 tree_example1("../trisignal/Events/run_01/tag_1_delphes_events.root") /* invoking function corresponding to '.x' */
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/mnt/c/1/MG5_aMC_v2_6_6/Delphes/examples/tree_example1.C:12:6: note: candidate function not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided
void tree_example1 ()
```

I am just trying to run a simple code where I am creating a TTree. 
Here is my code:

```
/*
#ifdef __CLING__
R__LOAD_LIBRARY(libDelphes)
#include "classes/DelphesClasses.h"
#include "external/ExRootAnalysis/ExRootTreeReader.h"
#include "external/ExRootAnalysis/ExRootResult.h"
#else
class ExRootTreeReader;
class ExRootResult;
#endif
*/
void tree_example1 ()
{
  //gSystem->Load("libDelphes");

  // Create chain of root trees
  //TChain chain("Delphes");
  //chain.Add(inputFile);
  //Open the input file and Create a simple tree
  TFile *f = new TFile("eventstrial.root", "RECREATE");
  TTree *tree = new TTree("T", "simple tree");
  //TTree *tree = &chain;
  TRandom r;

  //Filling Histograms
  TH1F *hist = new TH1F("hist", "", 100, 0., 2.);
    //Set up the variables
  Float_t px, py, pz, pt;
  Double_t random;
  UShort_t i;

    //Set Variables to Tree's Branches

  tree->Branch("px", &px, "px/F");
  tree->Branch("py", &py, "py/F");
  tree->Branch("pz", &py, "py/F");
  tree->Branch("pt", &pt, "pt/F");
  tree->Branch("random", &random, "random/D");

  for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
  {
    r.Rannor(px,py);
    pt = std::sqrt(px*px + py*py);
    tree->Fill();
  }
  f->Write();
  f->Close();
   tree->Draw("pt>>hist");
   hist->SetLineColor(3);
   hist->Draw("same");
}
```

I type in my ROOT terminal:  root -l 'examples/tree_example1.C("../trisignal/Events/run_01/tag_1_delphes_events.root")'

If I write 
root -l tree_example1.C

I get this error:

```
root [0]
Processing tree_example1.C...

 *** Break *** segmentation violation
 Generating stack trace...
 0x00007fdcdda680a0 in cling::IncrementalExecutor::executeWrapper(llvm::StringRef, cling::Value*) const + 0x380 from /home/cucip/builddir/lib/libCling.so
 0x00007fdcdd9fae77 in cling::Interpreter::RunFunction(clang::FunctionDecl const*, cling::Value*) + 0xa7 from /home/cucip/builddir/lib/libCling.so
 0x00007fdcdd9fc4df in cling::Interpreter::EvaluateInternal(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, cling::CompilationOptions, cling::Value*, cling::Transaction**, unsigned long) + 0x1df from /home/cucip/builddir/lib/libCling.so
 0x00007fdcddac61f1 in cling::MetaSema::actOnxCommand(llvm::StringRef, llvm::StringRef, cling::Value*) + 0x591 from /home/cucip/builddir/lib/libCling.so
 0x00007fdcddad6084 in cling::MetaParser::isXCommand(cling::MetaSema::ActionResult&, cling::Value*) + 0x194 from /home/cucip/builddir/lib/libCling.so
 0x00007fdcddad7476 in cling::MetaParser::isCommand(cling::MetaSema::ActionResult&, cling::Value*) + 0xa6 from /home/cucip/builddir/lib/libCling.so
 0x00007fdcddabf64b in cling::MetaProcessor::process(llvm::StringRef, cling::Interpreter::CompilationResult&, cling::Value*, bool) + 0x10b from /home/cucip/builddir/lib/libCling.so
 0x00007fdcdd97b68e in <unknown> from /home/cucip/builddir/lib/libCling.so
 0x00007fdcdd98fe72 in <unknown> from /home/cucip/builddir/lib/libCling.so
 0x00007fdcdd984537 in <unknown> from /home/cucip/builddir/lib/libCling.so
 0x00007fdce3112908 in TApplication::ExecuteFile(char const*, int*, bool) at /home/cucip/root-6.18.04/core/base/src/TApplication.cxx:1156 from /home/cucip/builddir/lib/libCore.so
 0x00007fdce31120ac in TApplication::ProcessLine(char const*, bool, int*) at /home/cucip/root-6.18.04/core/base/src/TApplication.cxx:1007 from /home/cucip/builddir/lib/libCore.so
 0x00007fdce35e18e2 in TRint::ProcessLineNr(char const*, char const*, int*) at /home/cucip/root-6.18.04/core/rint/src/TRint.cxx:762 from /home/cucip/builddir/lib/libRint.so
 0x00007fdce35e31d9 in TRint::Run(bool) at /home/cucip/root-6.18.04/core/rint/src/TRint.cxx:421 from /home/cucip/builddir/lib/libRint.so
 0x00007fdce3c00a0c in <unknown> from /home/cucip/builddir/bin/root.exe
 0x00007fdce2571b97 in __libc_start_main + 0xe7 from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
 0x00007fdce3c00a6a in _start + 0x2a from /home/cucip/builddir/bin/root.exe
Root >
```

Comment: Your comments on an answer below make this question seem to be asking for a basic tutorial on functions/methods with parameters. That is considered to be too broad, i.e. lack focus. Your best path is to find a few tutorials on constructs you are trying to use and make a simpler program which just practices using them. This is an article on the general concept I am referring to. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you compiler says :

**requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided
void tree_example1 ()**

you have called tree_example1 with one argument instead of zero.
redifine the function to accept the path

Comment: Where do I give it an argument. That is what I do not understand

Comment: I tried root -l examples/tree_example1.C but that doesn't work I get a different error.

Comment: the issue you have is not so hard. As @Yunnosch says you should take some tutorial or book on functions in c++.

Comment: @Yunnosch I am actually getting this directly from a tutorial. I am following along the tutorial step by step but stumbled upon this unexpected error. The second part of the tutorial works but not this first part.